# Trigger Beam ParDo at window closing only

Tags: apache-beam

I have a pipeline that read events from Kafka. I want to count and log the event count only when the window closes. By doing this I will only have one output log per Kafka partition/shard on each window. I use a timestamp in the header which I truncate to the hour to create a collection of hourly timestamps. I group the timestamps by hour and I log the hourly timestamp and count. This log will be sent to Grafana to create a dashboard with the counts.

Below is how I fetch the data from Kafka and where it defines the window duration:

```
int windowDuration = 5;
p.apply("Read from Kafka",KafkaIO.<byte[], GenericRecord>read()
            .withBootstrapServers(options.getSourceBrokers().get())
            .withTopics(srcTopics)
            .withKeyDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializer(ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider
            .of(options.getSchemaRegistryUrl().get(), options.getSubject().get()))
                    .commitOffsetsInFinalize())
  .apply("Windowing of " + windowDuration +" seconds" , 
            Window.<KafkaRecord<byte[], GenericRecord>>into(
            FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(windowDuration))));
```

The next step in the pipeline is to produce two collections from the above collection one with the events as GenericRecord and the other with the hourly timestamp, see below. I want a trigger (I believe) to be applied only two the collection holding the counts. So that it only prints the count once per window. Currently as is, it prints a count every time it reads from Kafka creating a large number of entries.

```
  tuplePCollection.get(createdOnTupleTag)
  .apply(Count.perElement())
  .apply( MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
  .via( (KV<Long,Long> recordCount) -> recordCount.getKey() +
    ": " + recordCount.getValue()))
  .apply( ParDo.of(new LoggerFn.logRecords<String>()));
```

Here is the DoFn I use to log the counts:

```
 class LoggerFn<T> extends DoFn<T, T> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void process(ProcessContext c) {
            T e = (T)c.element();
            LOGGER.info(e);
            c.output(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the trigger “Window.ClosingBehavior”. You need to specify under which conditions a final pane will be created when a window is permanently closed. You can use these options:

- **FIRE_ALWAYS**: Always Fire the last Pane.
- **FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY**: Only Fire the last pane if there is new data since
  previous firing.

You can see this example.

```
// We first specify to never emit any panes
 .triggering(Never.ever())
 
 // We then specify to fire always when closing the window. This will emit a
 // single final pane at the end of allowedLateness
 .withAllowedLateness(allowedLateness, Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS)
 .discardingFiredPanes())
```

You can see more information about this [trigger](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.ClosingBehavior.html).

Comment: Wouldn't this apply to both of my PCollections/data-sets? I am only want the trigger to apply to a PCollection. But I am not sure if this is possible. I know about the solution you posted. That will trigger only once but for both PCollections one is very large and I am affraid it will use more memory. Because instead of writing to a file the events as they come it will be holding them in memory.

Comment: @Fabio  You can put the count at the end of their pipeline, and then add a window/trigger to display that value every hour.
You can see a few looping counter examples here:   https://beam.apache.org/blog/looping-timers/

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: Yes but I did not need it to add another window/trigger just one while I am reading from Kafka is sufficient to control both collections. Since the event timestamp is processing time I don't need lateness.